# external javascript will not work

Tags: javascript, html

The problem I'm having is getting my external JavaScript file to work with my html.

The point of the javascript is to highlight required fields when they are submitted empty and then return to their original color when clicked on or (onfocus).

I don't know how to correctly link the javascript to make it apply to the html

I tried using onload="function();" within the < body > but I know that isn't right. I'm just completely lost, so any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

HTML here: http://pastebin.com/Zwsqn7kr

CSS here: http://pastebin.com/zpNkpALd

JavaScript here:

```
window.onload = function () {

document.getElementById('mainForm').onsubmit = function (e) {

    var t = document.getElementsById("title");
    var d = document.getElementsById("description");
    var l = document.getElementsById("license");
    var tv = document.getElementsById("title").value;
    var dv = document.getElementsById("description").value;

    if (tv == null || tv === "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        title.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        title.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }

    if (dv == null || dv === "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        description.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        description.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }

    if (!l.checked) {
        e.preventDefault();
        license.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        license.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }

    t.onfocus = function () {
        title.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        title.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    };

    d.onfocus = function () {
        description.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        description.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    };

    l.onfocus = function () {
        license.style.backgroundColor = "EBF4FB";
        license.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "EBF4FB";
    };

};

};
```

Comment: what is it doing or not doing? *"will not work"* is not debuggable.

Comment: i don't think the javascript is correctly linked to the html if at all

Comment: What errors does it show in the console.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )  line 13 of html.  It is referring to the onload="function();" portion that i added.  Which i know is incorrect, because when i remove it i have no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you replace `document.getElementsById` with `document.getElementById` it's will start highlight wrong fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the line that links to the script just before the end of the `body`.